# Java private member access

Tags: java, oop, object, member

I'm a beginner with Java, but I thought that private members could only be accessed via a "accessor" public method (get or set for example) so it troubles me that this works:

```
class Queue {

    private char[] q;
    private int putloc, getloc; // the put and get indices

    // Construct an empty queue given its size
    Queue(int size) {
        this.q = new char[size];
        this.putloc = this.getloc = 0;
    }

    // Construct a queue from a queue
    Queue(Queue ob) {
        this.putloc = ob.putloc;
        this.getloc = ob.getloc;

        this.q = new char[ob.q.length];

        // copy elements
        for(int i=this.getloc; i<this.putloc; i++) {
            this.q[i] = ob.q[i];
        }
    }

    // Construct a queue with initial values
    Queue(char[] a) {
        this.putloc = 0;
        this.getloc = 0;
        this.q = new char[a.length];

        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) this.put(a[i]);
    }

    // Put a character into the queue
    void put(char ch) {
        if (this.putloc == q.length) {
            System.out.println(" - Queue is full");
            return;
        }

        q[this.putloc++] = ch;
    }

    // Get character from the queue
    char get() {
        if (this.getloc == this.putloc) {
            System.out.println(" - Queue is empty");
            return (char) 0;
        }

        return this.q[this.getloc++];
    }

    void print() {
        for(char ch: this.q) {
            System.out.println(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

UseQueue is a separate file:

```
class UseQueue {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Queue Program");

        // Construct 10-element empty queue
        Queue q1 = new Queue(10);
        System.out.println("Q1: ");
        q1.print();

        char[] name = {'S', 'e', 'b', 'a', 's'};
        // Construct queue from array
        Queue q2 = new Queue(name);
        System.out.println("Q2: ");
        q2.print();

        // put some chars into q1
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            q1.put((char) ('A' + i));
        }

        System.out.println("Q1 after adding chars: ");
        q1.print();

        // Construct new queue from another queue
        Queue q3 = new Queue(q1);
        System.out.println("Q3 built from Q1: ");
        q3.print();

    }
}
```

As you can see, q, putloc and getloc are declared as private in Queue, so why I can directly access those values from the overload constructor? shouldn't be only accessible through a method such as getQ, getPutLoc, getLoc or something similar? (methods which I have not implemented).

Comment: Private members can be accessed anywhere in the containing class.

Comment: Which constructor (or constructors) did you think _shouldn't_ have been able to access those variables directly?  And which one (or ones) should have? And why?

Comment: But that's my point. It's not being accessed directly from the class per se, but from an object. Queue(Queue ob) receives an object and it's accessing directly the private properties of that object

Answer (score 1):

Constructor is also a public method. That's why it works.

Comment: But that constructor is accessing the properties of an object that is being passed as parameter. Queue(Queue ob)  receives an object and it's accessing directly the private properties of that object.